# c++ error while loading shared libararies sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbAoz.png) is a picture of what I am trying to do.

I tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$home/hassan/c++ (which is the folder that you see)

or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=home/hassan/c++

with no luck

please help!

thak you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with full paths:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd -P`
```

Not sure if the next step is required, but if it still gives you fits, symbolically link the so.2 file:

```
ln -s libsfml-graphics.so.2 libsfml-graphics.so
```